# A way for the Command+TAB app switcher to continuously cycle instead of stop at the end

Tags: macos, mac

Is there anyway to have the Command+TAB app switcher continuously cycle instead of stop at the end when you hold down command and tab like it did pre Mavericks?

Comment: Didn't notice the behavior change till your question. But I'm curious to know why one would want it to cycle beyond the end since at that point you've passed by all the apps and while still holding the Command key a quick release and press of TAB will take you to the beginning and cycle to the end again. Am I missing something? (I'm glad you pointed it out for me, though.)

Comment: Because it used to be that it would cycle so fast it was simply easier to hold down and continue the cycle till it came around again to the app you wanted. The way things are now, if you pass by the desired app, you have to continue to hold command, let go of tab, awkwardly add in shift, and then tap tab to go backwards. It was simply easier to just let the cycle fly through and start again till it hit the app that is desired.

Comment: I don't think it's that complex. If you pass by the  desired app you just let it go to the end and stop. Then a quick release and press of the TAB key (without releasing the Command key) starts the cycle again from the beginning. The brief pause before restarting the cycle helps me be ready to stop at the desired app the next time through. If the Command key is not released it's easy to go around the cycle as many times as necessary.

Comment: Sure, there are ways, but perhaps there was something about watching the app switcher zoom by many times as I paused and thought about what I want to do next I really miss. Also, holding down buttons im already holding to get where I want is a lot easier than adding in shift, or removing tab, and then hitting tab again. I realize it's a minor ask relatively, — I just really wish I could restore the previous behaviour.

Comment: Sorry I can't provide any answer, but at least I can tell it's NOT Mavericks related, or I have collector one. Mine was working the old way a few days ago, then all of a sudden for an unknown reason it stopped. Using another session or booting in safe boot didn't help.

Comment: Since it sounds like your main complain is due to missing the desired app while cycling - did you consider using the mouse to select the app from the switcher?

Answer (score 2):

Even as early as Lion, <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> when held continuously stops at the end and does not cycle. Releasing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key and then pressing it again resets the cycle to the beginning. It is not necessary to release <kbd>command</kbd>. Releasing <kbd>tab</kbd>and then pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> will reverse scroll through the app listing.

To the very best of my knowledge, this behaviour is hardcoded and not configurable by the end user.