# Application switcher not cycling anymore on hold

Tags: macos, application-switcher

10.9.5 here

Suddenly my Application Switcher won't cycle anymore on hold. It still can cycle between apps one by one, but if I hold command tab it will stop after reaching the right end of the row. Before that it used to keep cycling until I release command tab.

It's not so much that the loss of this minor feature is annoying, it is *why* it happened in the first place. As far as I know I didn't install any new app nor change anything. I found out that the same is true for any session not just mine. I also tried safe boot to no avail.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, although I searched it's clearly a dupe. No answer anyway unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks this is a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/145571/33618).

I have the same situation - no cycling beyond endpoints (cycling backwards you can do via Ctrl + Shift + Tab).